# Eliminate duplicate words across lines

Tags: sed

I'd like a sed script that eliminates repeated words in a text file on one or more lines. For example:

```
this is is is a text file file it is littered with duplicate words
words words on one or more lines lines
lines
  lines
```

should transform to:

```
this is a text file it is littered with duplicate words
on one or more lines
```

This awk script produces the correct output:

```
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        word = $i

        if (word != last) {
            if (i < NF) {
                next_word = $(i+1)

                if (word != next_word) {
                    printf("%s ", word)
                }
            } else {
                printf("%s\n", word)
            }
        }
    }

    last = word
}
```

but I'd really like a sed "one-liner".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with GNU sed, at least for the example input:

```
$ sed -Ez ':a;s/(\<\S+)(\s+)\1\s+/\1\2/g;ta' infile
This is a text file and is littered with duplicate words
on one or more lines
```

The `-E` option is just there to avoid having to escape the capture group parentheses and `+` quantifiers.

`-z` treats the input as null byte separated, i.e., as a single line.

The commmand is then structured as

```
:a      # label
s///g   # substitution
ta      # jump to label if substitution did something
```

And the substitution is this:

```
s/(\<\S+)(\s+)\1\s+/\1\2/g
```

- First capture group: `(\<\S+)` – a complete word (start of word boundary, one or more non-space characters
- Second capture group: `(\s+)` – any number of blanks after that first word
- `\1\s+` – the first word again plus whatever blanks follow it

This preserves the whitespace after the first word and discards the whitespace after the duplicate.

Note that `-E`, `-z`, `\<`, `\S` and `\s` are all GNU extensions to POSIX sed.

Answer (score 0):

With sed, you can use

`sed -E 's/([a-z]+) +\1/\1/g'`

Note that it works for duplicates. Not for triplicates or line breaks.

This can be fixed, by joining all the lines and looping.

`sed -E ':a;N;s/(\b[a-z]+\b)([ \n])[ \n]*\b\1\b */\1\2/g;ba'`

Comment: Yep; got to the same expression...but fails on spanning repeats.

Comment: Also, that may work in GNU sed, but doesn't appear to work in BSD/macos.

Comment: This creates a single line of output, though, and the expected output still has linebreaks.

Comment: It should be OK now. I keep track of the chars between duplicated words and gobble useless spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -En '
    H
    ${
        g
        s/^\n//
        s/(\<([[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]]+)(\2([[:space:]]+|$))+/\1/g
        p
    }
' file
```

```
This is a text file with duplicate words
on one or more lines
```

where

- `H` -- append each line to the hold space
- `${...}` -- on the last line, perform the enclosed commands
- `g` -- replace pattern space with the contents of the hold space
- `s/^\n//` -- remove leading newline (side-effect of `H` on first line)
- `s/(\<([[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]]+)(\2([[:space:]]+|$))+/\1/g`
  `..1..2............2............1..........................`

  - the key here is to capture the text and the spaces separately so that the back reference can match with differing whitespace.
  - captured expression #1 is the first word and it's whitespace (which can contain newlines), and the capture #2 is just the word.